# Server has antivirus. Do I need to enable external locking on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, centos

From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/external-locking.html):

> If you only read tables with other programs, external locking is not required

Assuming the bytes of MySQL files does not match viruses, the antivirus will not change the [*contents*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404(v=vs.85).aspx) of the file.

However, the antivirus may change file attributes and *"do some other things"*.

Do I need to enable external locking on MySQL to prevent (possible) data corruption?

(I'm using both InnoDB and MyISAM.)

Comment: Linux or Windows. You've tagged with both.

Comment: @Phil, Both. Currently Windows Server 2003 but planning to move to CentOS/linux.

Answer (score 1):

No, external locking is (was) only needed for MyISAM when you tried to execute several processes on the same data directory, such as two server instances, or an instance and a file repair.

Sincerely, I would be surprised if that page manual was accurate and was still fully supported. In any case, it is mostly impossible to do that now, as InnoDB (default engine) disallows 2 instances on the same server at the same time.

In summary, an antivirus scan is not a problem for MySQL, unless it changes the files or moves them away; and if the resources it uses do not interfere with the database execution. I wouldn't run, however, an antivirus software on a production server, unless it was for scanning the network (emails or desktop clients).

Comment: Would writing to [alternative data streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(file_system)#Microsoft) (e.g. flagging) affect the MySQL server? And what happens when the antivirus locks some of the files that MySQL requires?